# how to change prettify class prettyprint to other class name we like?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am using Syntax Highlighter on my blog for prettifying codes. Now I want to change it to Google Open Source Prettify.

In Syntax HighLighter, we highlight the code by calling `<pre class="brush: js;">` But in Google Prettify it was `<pre class="prettyprint">`.

So, It is very hard to replace the `<pre class="brush: js;">` with `<pre class="prettyprint">` on my blog. Is there is any way to replace or change the class name of syntax highlighter with Prettify was appreciable.

Comment: can't you use a text editor ?in  netbeans there is a option find and replace

Comment: What text editor you are talking about? I want to highlights the code in my blog.

Comment: you can retrieve the source code of your blog then edit . then replace with new source code ?

Comment: I already said it was not only on one page. It was in a lot of articles that I published in my blog. So it is very hard to edit each and every page and replace the `<pre class="brush: js;">` with `<pre class="prettyprint">`

Comment: then how about replace class `prettyprint` to `brush: js;` using javascript .

Comment: if you are not using cdn or external of googles prety library you can edit that js .so you don't need to add function to all blogs

Comment: But I want to use CDN. In Blogger, there is no option to host files. Also, I don't want to use Cloud Storages for doing this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hold the `pre` tag and remove all the classes from it and then add `prettyprint` to it. Just a line of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("pre").removeClass().addClass('prettyprint');
 });
```

Comment: Can I replace `class="brush: js;` instead of `pre` ?

Comment: Yep, you can. Or you can add multiple classes like - `class="brush: css;` , `class="brush: python;`

Btw, what is address of your blog. We can test it in console. Did you already added Google prettyprint class to your blog?

Comment: check the updated answer - it will remove all class starting with 'brush'. so in this way, you can get rid off all brush classes!

Comment: @MuhsinMohamedPc, I have edited my answer, this is the best way with clean classes.